# Play Media Player stream on firefox and chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video-streaming, media-player, windows-media-player

I have a media player stream live on an ip, e.g: `192.168.1.100` and port `8888`

with following code it is played on IE, but not in forefox, how can i play stream on firefox?

```
<object id="mediaplayer" classid="clsid:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" 
codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#version=5,1,52,701" 
standby="loading microsoft windows media player components..."   
type="application/x-oleobject" width="320" height="310">
    <param name="filename" value="http://192.168.1.100:8888">
    <param name="animationatstart" value="true">
    <param name="transparentatstart" value="true">
    <param name="autostart" value="true">
    <param name="showcontrols" value="true">
    <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
    <param name="windowlessvideo" value="true">
 <embed src="http://192.168.1.100:8888" type="application/x-mplayer2"
      pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" 
      autostart="true" showcontrols="true" showstatusbar="1"
      bgcolor="white" width="320" height="310">
</object>
```

Answer (score 2):

The same HTML won't work in any other browser since you are using ActiveX which is a Microsoft technology.

So you would have to create a different HTML/JavaScript player. But since your stream plays back in IE with an older MediaPlayer plugin - most likely your stream format is a Windows Media format.
Windows Media formats are a Microsoft technology and likely won't play in any other browser.